# how to pop out label name using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery to pop out **label name from a row which is checked** and if the row is not checked , it should not pop out but it is popping out on for all 3 rows

HTML code :

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>APPLICATION | </td>
    <td>ENV | </td>
    <td>REGION | </td>
    <td>URL | </td>
 <td><input type="button" value="Edit" class="edit">
 <input type="button" value="Update" class="update"> 
 <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="reset">    </td>       
</tr> 
<tr>
 <td><label class='applabel'>app1</label> <input type="text" class="app" hidden></td>
    <td>env1 | </td>
    <td>region1 | </td>
    <td>url1 | </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="ed-up"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label class='applabel'>app2</label> <input type="text" class="app" hidden></td>
    <td>env2 | </td>
    <td>region2 | </td>
    <td>url2 | </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="ed-up"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label class='applabel'>app3</label> <input type="text" class="app" hidden> </td>
    <td>env3 | </td>
    <td>region3 | </td>
    <td>url3 | </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="ed-up"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

javascript code :

```
$(function() {

$('.reset').on('click',function () {
  $(':checkbox').prop('checked',false);
  $(':text').hide();
  $('.applabel').show();  
});

$('.edit').on('click',function () {
   $('.ed-up').each(function(){
       if($('.ed-up').prop('checked') == true)
      alert($(this).next('.applabel').text()); 

   });
});

 });
```

I am using each method to iterate over the rows but and want to pop out the row I mean alert only when the checkbox is checked

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/9cqb0hym/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider following: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.applabel').text()`

```
$('.edit').on('click',function () {
   $('.ed-up').each(function(){
       if($(this).prop('checked') == true)
         alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.applabel').text()); 
   });
});
```

[**Updated DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9cqb0hym/6/)

---

Changes

```
if($('.ed-up').prop('checked') == true)
//changed to
if($(this).prop('checked') == true)
```

---

```
alert($(this).next('.applabel').text() );
//changed to 
alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.applabel').text());
```

Comment: thnks a lot man , this is the concept i need to learn the most

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the context that `.each()` passes to the function.

The following line:

```
if($('.ed-up').prop('checked') == true)
```

Only checks the `.checked` property of the *first* match for `.ed-up`. You should be using `this`:

```
if($(this).prop('checked') == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
$(function() {
  $('.reset').on('click',function () {
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked',false);
    $(':text').hide();
    $('.applabel').show();  
  });

  $('.edit').on('click',function () {
     $('.ed-up').each(function(){
       if($(this).prop('checked') == true)
          alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.applabel').text());
     });
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9cqb0hym/8/)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Its not good to use other's code when they have already given same solution. But nice effort of **copy past**.

Comment: @manwal you did **small mistake**, i corrected that code post my answer. This is not copy past.

Comment: Now you changed that code correctly.
I told this line only.
if($('.ed-up').prop('checked') == true)
//changed to
if($(this).prop('checked') == true)